# C# how to create an event handler for listBox1.MouseDown?

Tags: winforms, events, click, mouse, handler

I have been trying to make it so that when i right click a listbox item it selects it, but I can't figure out how to declare an event handler for my listbox for mouse down.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in c#:

`listBox1.MouseDown += delegate(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){ ... };`